# ¿Por qué solo puedo realizar un update en mariaDB (MySQL) con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

**ESTRUCTURA DE LA TABLA**

El `dni` y el `medicamento` tienen índice INDEX. El `dni` se repite para el mismo paciente y los medicamentos se pueden repetir, pero no para el mismo paciente.

| dni | medicamento | dosis | inicio | fin | observaciones |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dni_1 | medicamento_1 |  |  |  |  |
| dni_1 | medicamento_2 |  |  |  |  |
| dni_2 | medicamento_1 |  |  |  |  |
| dni_2 | medicamento_2 |  |  |  |  |

**CÓDIGO PHP**

```
$datos_medicacion = $_POST['datos_medicacion']; 

var_export($datos_medicacion); = 'medicamento_1 (descripción_1),2 a la semana,2023-07-01,2023-12-24,Ejemplo 1 de observaciones,61354354F,medicamento_1 (descripción_1)[_]medicamento_2 (descripción_2),1 litro al día,2023-07-01,2024-12-30,Ejemplo 2 de observaciones.,61354354F,medicamento_2 (descripción_2)' 

var_dump($datos_medicacion); = string(274) "medicamento_1 (descripción_1),2 a la semana,2023-07-01,2023-12-24,Ejemplo 1 de observaciones,61354354F,medicamento_1 (descripción_1)[_]medicamento_2 (descripción_2),1 litro al día,2023-07-01,2024-12-30,Ejemplo 2 de observaciones.,61354354F,medicamento_2 (descripción_2)"

$array_datos_medicacion = explode('[_]', $datos_medicacion); 
            
foreach($array_datos_medicacion as $valor){ 

    $array = explode(',', $valor);
                
    mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE medicacion SET medicamento = '$array[0]', dosis = '$array[1]', inicio = '$array[2]', fin = '$array[3]', observaciones = '$array[4]' WHERE dni = '$array[5]' AND medicamento = '$array[6]'");

} 
            
mysqli_close($conexion);

exit;
```

**QUE QUIERO HACER**

Quiero actualizar todas las líneas y columnas (`medicamento`, `dosis`, `inicio`, `fin` y `observaciones`), que correspondan al paciente en cuestión, usando como filtro el `dni` y el medicamento. Los datos provienen de un formulario en HTML y son enviados al servidor a través de AJAX y procesados con PHP.

**RESULTADOS**

He intentado realizar varios `update` usando un bucle `foreach`, pero solo me realiza una consulta. También he intentado usar `mysqli_multi_query`, pero solo me realiza una consulta.

¿Alguien sabe como podría solucionar este problema?

Comment: No está demás mencionar que tu consulta es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL. Lectura recomendada: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](/q/18232). Por otra parte: ¿qué pasaría si alguna de tus actualizaciones falla? ¿Revertirás las actualizaciones previas?

Comment: Gracias Padaleiana por responder. Ya eliminé las etiquetas javascript y html. Si las actualizaciones fallan, que espero que no pase, ¿Cual sería la mejor opción?. Pero el problema es que solo me ejecuta un solo update, da igual los que ponga (3, 4, etc), solo me ejecuta un update. También voy a ir mirando como evitar la inyección SQL. Gracias.

Comment: A lo mejor lo puedo hacer todo con un solo update; pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Hola @Evelio. Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el resultado de `var_export($datos_medicacion)`?

Comment: Nada podremos decirte sin saber con qué datos estás trabajando. Coloca un `var_dump($_POST);` al inicio de tu código, luego copia y pega el resultado del mismo en la pregunta pulsando en [edit] para analizar los datos y su estructura.

Comment: Ya e puesto los resultados de var_export y var_dump, los cuales e optenido de la consola de DeeTools del chromium. El chromium lo utilizo para programas en html, css y javascript y el gedit de linux para programas en php. Por lo que e estado mirando sobre las consultas preparadas, sirven tanto para mejorar la seguridad, como para realizar consultas multiples. Voy a probar este sistema y después os cuento. Hasta pronto y gracias.

Comment: Hola @Evelio, como no me "arrobaste" no me entere de tu último comentario. Si te fijas en la primer parte de cadena que obtenes, dice _'medicamento_1 (descripción_1),2 a la semana,2023-07-01,2023-12-24,Ejemplo 1 de observaciones,61354354F,medicamento_1 (descripción_1)'_. A simple vista el error es que lo que sería `medicamento` (_la última parte de la cadena_), el valor es igual a `medicamento_1 (descripción_1)` y esto es lo que causa tu problema. El script que arma la cadena para enviar los datos, lo esta haciendo mal. Saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué significa: arrobaste?

Comment: Ya solucioné el problema. Lo que ocurría era que para el dni y el medicamento del WHERE de la consulta, yo obtenía los datos del texto de un onclick de un buttun y después no cambiaba el texto del mismo. Lo que significa que en la siguiente solicitud, los datos enviados al servidor, no coincidían con los datos de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCIÓN**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
hijos_tbody[i].children[i_2].children[0].setAttribute("onclick", `if(confirm('¿Realmente desea eliminar la fila?')){filtro('eliminar_medicamento','61354354F','${value_medicamento}')}`);
```

**PHP**

```
#Sentencia preparada, etapa 1: preparación. Marcadores = ? 
if (!$sentencia = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE medicacion SET medicamento =?, dosis =?, inicio =?, fin =?, observaciones =? WHERE dni =? AND medicamento =?")){
  echo "Falló la preparación: ".$conexion->error;
  exit;
}

#Sentencia preparada, etapa 2: vincular y ejecutar 
foreach($array_datos_medicacion as $valor){  
  $array = explode(',', $valor);
                
  #vincular parámetros para marcadores
  $sentencia->bind_param('sssssss', $array[0], $array[1], $array[2], $array[3], $array[4], $array[5], $array[6]);
                
  #ejecutar la consulta
  if (!$sentencia->execute()) {
    echo "Falló la ejecución: ".$sentencia->error;
    exit;
  }
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
```